# Possible bug when joining pandas DataFrames with different Timezones

Tags: python, pandas, pytz

I am trying to join two pandas dataframes with the pd.DataFrame.join function, but there is a problem when I try to change the datetime of an existing index. I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import numpy as np

# Creating date ranges
sim_date = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-12-31', freq='1H', tz='UTC')
obs_date = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-12-31', freq='1H')

# Creating DataFrames with the time ranges as indices
sim = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(interim_date)), index=interim_date, columns=['Sim'])
obs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(obs_date)), index=obs_date, columns=['Obs'])

# Changing the timezone of the observed data index
obs.index = obs.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('America/Phoenix')

# Printing the result of the join
print(pd.DataFrame.join(sim, obs).dropna())
```

Which yields:

```
                                Sim       Obs
1980-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  0.844345  0.117649
1980-01-01 01:00:00+00:00  0.505349  0.755907
1980-01-01 02:00:00+00:00  0.799555  0.169102
1980-01-01 03:00:00+00:00  0.194750  0.704400
1980-01-01 04:00:00+00:00  0.459079  0.241803
1980-01-01 05:00:00+00:00  0.496936  0.726264
1980-01-01 06:00:00+00:00  0.515039  0.989569
1980-01-01 07:00:00+00:00  0.271105  0.488859
1980-01-01 08:00:00+00:00  0.545269  0.434904
1980-01-01 09:00:00+00:00  0.817365  0.067979
1980-01-01 10:00:00+00:00  0.051024  0.068993
1980-01-01 11:00:00+00:00  0.170346  0.510406
1980-01-01 12:00:00+00:00  0.518609  0.583602
1980-01-01 13:00:00+00:00  0.725753  0.402805
1980-01-01 14:00:00+00:00  0.134059  0.879183
1980-01-01 15:00:00+00:00  0.304070  0.773884
1980-01-01 16:00:00+00:00  0.742448  0.158367
1980-01-01 17:00:00+00:00  0.539499  0.067725
1980-01-01 18:00:00+00:00  0.349432  0.027337
1980-01-01 19:00:00+00:00  0.549015  0.078190
1980-01-01 20:00:00+00:00  0.089871  0.878931
1980-01-01 21:00:00+00:00  0.100849  0.359007
1980-01-01 22:00:00+00:00  0.290280  0.168759
1980-01-01 23:00:00+00:00  0.074420  0.881724
1980-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  0.091413  0.820616
```

but when I use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import numpy as np

interim_date = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-01-02', freq='1H', tz='UTC')
obs_date = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-01-02', freq='1H', tz='America/Phoenix')

sim = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(interim_date)), index=interim_date, columns=['Sim'])
obs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(obs_date)), index=obs_date, columns=['Obs'])

print(pd.DataFrame.join(sim, obs).dropna())
```

it yields:

```
                                Sim       Obs
1980-01-01 07:00:00+00:00  0.894766  0.509333
1980-01-01 08:00:00+00:00  0.805764  0.564251
1980-01-01 09:00:00+00:00  0.996807  0.856853
1980-01-01 10:00:00+00:00  0.494817  0.088286
1980-01-01 11:00:00+00:00  0.716468  0.947045
1980-01-01 12:00:00+00:00  0.808407  0.332764
1980-01-01 13:00:00+00:00  0.554688  0.959215
1980-01-01 14:00:00+00:00  0.389542  0.462384
1980-01-01 15:00:00+00:00  0.039566  0.850724
1980-01-01 16:00:00+00:00  0.634998  0.097579
1980-01-01 17:00:00+00:00  0.169957  0.390812
1980-01-01 18:00:00+00:00  0.113913  0.519487
1980-01-01 19:00:00+00:00  0.521354  0.260055
1980-01-01 20:00:00+00:00  0.910717  0.693063
1980-01-01 21:00:00+00:00  0.907878  0.190714
1980-01-01 22:00:00+00:00  0.625534  0.048584
1980-01-01 23:00:00+00:00  0.926966  0.815481
1980-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  0.841386  0.573255
```

It seems as though both methods should yield the same result, but it seems like in the first case the observed DataFrame index does not change, even though when I print it out it says that it changed... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two methods of construction are actually different.  For example, look at the first element of each index:

```
In [2]: obs_date1 = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-12-31', freq='1H') \
                      .tz_localize('UTC') \
                      .tz_convert('America/Phoenix')

In [3]: obs_date2 = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-12-31', freq='1H', 
                                  tz='America/Phoenix')

In [4]: obs_date1[0]
Out[4]: Timestamp('1979-12-31 17:00:00-0700', tz='America/Phoenix', freq='H')

In [5]: obs_date2[0]
Out[5]: Timestamp('1980-01-01 00:00:00-0700', tz='America/Phoenix', freq='H')
```

By doing `.tz_localize('UTC')`, you're basically appending the UTC timezone to each timestamp.  Then by using `tz_convert('America/Phoenix')` you're shifting the UTC timestamps back seven hours to the America/Phoenix timezone.  When you use this method and `join` against the UTC timestamps, this index get shifted back to UTC for alignment, and both indexes exactly match, hence nothing getting dropped in your `join`.

I think what you want for the first option is to just directly use `tz_localize('America/Phoenix')`:

```
In [6]: obs_date3 = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '1980-12-31', freq='1H') \
   ...:               .tz_localize('America/Phoenix')

In [7]: obs_date3[0]
Out[7]: Timestamp('1980-01-01 00:00:00-0700', tz='America/Phoenix', freq='H')
```

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now, I thought they were the same but I wasn't paying close enough attention. Thank you!